# Is it posible to port iOS frameworks to WatchOS

Tags: ios, frameworks, watchkit, apple-watch

I am currently making an application for the WATCH and would like to use a 3rd party iOS library which isn't built for WatchOS. Is it possible to port the iOS framework to make apps for WatchOS2?

Comment: If the framework is open-source, and does not use any features that are specific to iOS, you could build a watchOS version of the framework.

Answer (score 1):

yes it is. create a new target on the framework for watchOS.

Proceed to add all the files/functionality that you want to port.

Then create a dummy watchOS app and try building it. it will show you a bunch of build errors.

Then use preprocessor macros to seperate the code according to OS

```
#if TARGET_OS_WATCH 
//watchOS exclusive functionality would go here
#else
//iOS exclusive functionality would go here
#endif
```

or

```
#if !TARGET_OS_WATCH
//NON watchOS functionality would go here
#elif TARGET_OS_TV
// this is how you do else if with preprocessor. 
// in this case this code would only be executed on tvOS (Apple TV)
#endif

NSLog("Put all code that you want to run an ALL the different OS, outside of any #if checks");
```

This way you can specify which specific functions you want to port over to watchOS, but you can also create seperate logic for the same function depending on the OS (really useful with networking and UI stuff imo).

Lastly just build the dummy app (on watchOS) and then see why it doesn't build. Go in and fix the build errors, one by one (by either using preprocessor macros to comment out the code you can't/don't want to port, or writing OS specific code).

Depending on the size of your framework this can be a lot of work, but after a bit you keep running into the same issues so it become a bit of a braindead task to fix it.

Enjoy ;)